# web3 js send ether not broadcasting on main net

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, truffle, etherscan, nodejs

I am using folowing code sample to send ether between 2 of my own accounts, both have enough funds:

```
"use strict";
var Web3 = require('web3');
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
// Show Web3 where it needs to look for a connection to Ethereum.
//web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545'));
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/N6IIa2HvDYOovtgmPbhD'));
var gasPrice = "20";//or get with web3.eth.gasPrice
var gasLimit = '42000';
var addr = "...";
var toAddress = "....";
var amountToSend = web3.utils.toWei('0.0005', 'ether'); //$1
var nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(addr); //211;
var rawTransaction = {
"from": addr,
"nonce": web3.utils.toHex(nonce),
"gasPrice": web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('9', 'gwei')),
"gasLimit": web3.utils.toHex(gasLimit),
"to": toAddress,
"value": web3.utils.toHex(amountToSend) ,
"chainId": 1 //remember to change this
};
var privateKey = "...";
var privKey = new Buffer(privateKey, 'hex');
//console.log("privKey  : ", privKey);
var tx = new Tx(rawTransaction);
tx.sign(privKey);
var serializedTx = tx.serialize();
console.log('serializedTx : '+serializedTx);
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'), function(err, hash) {
if (!err)
{
console.log('Txn Sent and hash is '+hash);
let userBalance = (web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash));
console.log(userBalance);
userBalance.then(function(result) {
   console.log(result);
})

}
else
{
console.error(err);
}
});
```

however, what i get from console log is:

```
Txn Sent and hash is 0xab9a2265792203d787d0e08c7a808865b1d776d9a289d92ded2596c352b6e56c
Promise { <pending> }
null
```

this is not updated on etherscan or anywhere on main net. I am quite confused as there is nowhere telling me where I am wrong. Does someone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

just remove "from" address from your rawTransaction and try again.read about given link.
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#sendsignedtransaction